# Como fazer quebra de linha em uma tag no vue?

Tags: vue.js, img

[image: Quebra de linha necessária]

Gente, tô tentando fazer quebra de linha nas cartas ali da imagem mas não tô conseguindo. Já fiz, row, já fiz align (de todos os tipos), não tô conseguindo. Essas cartas estão armazenadas em um array, são 52 cartas, preciso mostrar 10 em cada linha.

O código que exibe essas cartas é esse aqui:

```
<h3 class="ma-4">Baralho</h3>
        <v-layout>
          <v-img class="ma-2 pa-3 carta" v-for="carta in todasAsCartas" :key="carta.id" :src="carta.image"></v-img>
        </v-layout>
```

e eles estão armazenados nesse array:

```
todasAsCartas:[
            { 'id': 1,     'nome': 'Dois de Ouros',      'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 2,     'nome': 'Três de Ouros',      'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 3,     'nome': 'Quatro de Ouros',    'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 4,     'nome': 'Cinco de Ouros',     'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 5,     'nome': 'Seis de Ouros',      'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 6,     'nome': 'Sete de Ouros',      'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 7,     'nome': 'Oito de Ouros',      'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 8,     'nome': 'Nove de Ouros',      'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 9,     'nome': 'Dez de Ouros',       'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 10,    'nome': 'Dama de Ouros',      'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 11,    'nome': 'Valete de Ouros',    'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 12,    'nome': 'Reis de Ouros',      'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 13,    'nome': 'Ás de Ouros',        'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 14,    'nome': 'Dois de Espadas',    'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 15,    'nome': 'Três de Espadas',    'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 16,    'nome': 'Quatro de Espadas',  'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 17,    'nome': 'Cinco de Espadas',   'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 18,    'nome': 'Seis de Espadas',    'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 19,    'nome': 'Sete de Espadas',    'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 20,    'nome': 'Oito de Espadas',    'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 21,    'nome': 'Nove de Espadas',    'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 22,    'nome': 'Dez de Espadas',     'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 23,    'nome': 'Dama de Espadas',    'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 24,    'nome': 'Valete de Espadas',  'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 25,    'nome': 'Reis de Espadas',    'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 26,    'nome': 'Ás de Espadas',      'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 27,    'nome': 'Dois de Copas',      'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 28,    'nome': 'Três de Copas',      'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 29,    'nome': 'Quatro de Copas',    'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 30,    'nome': 'Cinco de Copas',     'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 31,    'nome': 'Seis de Copas',      'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 32,    'nome': 'Sete de Copas',      'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 33,    'nome': 'Oito de Copas',      'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 34,    'nome': 'Nove de Copas',      'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 35,    'nome': 'Dez de Copas',       'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 36,    'nome': 'Dama de Copas',      'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 37,    'nome': 'Valete de Copas',    'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 38,    'nome': 'Reis de Copas',      'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 39,    'nome': 'Ás de Copas',        'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 40,    'nome': 'Dois de Paus',       'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 41,    'nome': 'Três de Paus',       'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 42,    'nome': 'Quatro de Paus',     'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 43,    'nome': 'Cinco de Paus',      'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 44,    'nome': 'Seis de Paus',       'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 45,    'nome': 'Sete de Paus',       'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 46,    'nome': 'Oito de Paus',       'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 47,    'nome': 'Nove de Paus',       'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 48,    'nome': 'Dez de Paus',        'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Paus,',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 49,    'nome': 'Dama de Paus',       'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 50,    'nome': 'Valete de Paus',     'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 51,    'nome': 'Reis de Paus',       'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 52,    'nome': 'Ás de Paus',         'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdepaus.png')}           
        ],
```

O código todo está aqui:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout>

      <!-- card do game -->
      <v-card height dark full-width width="1000px">

        <!-- --Botão para sacar uma carta do monte-- -->

        <v-btn class="botaoEstilizado" @click="sacarCartaDoBaralho">
            Sacar +1
        </v-btn>

        <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

        <!-- --Inicio das Cartas da Mão do Player 1-- -->

        <h3 class="ma-4">Cartas na Mão</h3>

        <v-layout align-baseline row>
          <v-img class="ma-2 pa-3 carta" v-for="item in cartasNaMao" :key="item.id" :src="item.image"></v-img>
        </v-layout> 

        <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

        <!-- --Inicio do monte-- -->

        <h3 class="ma-4">Baralho</h3>
        <v-layout>
          <v-img class="ma-2 pa-3 carta" v-for="carta in todasAsCartas" :key="carta.id" :src="carta.image"></v-img>
        </v-layout>

        <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

      </v-card>     
      <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>


<script>


export default {

    data: () => ({
        size: 'sm',
        baralhoTeste: [],

        numeroAleatorioGerado: [],

        todasAsCartas:[
            { 'id': 1,     'nome': 'Dois de Ouros',      'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 2,     'nome': 'Três de Ouros',      'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 3,     'nome': 'Quatro de Ouros',    'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 4,     'nome': 'Cinco de Ouros',     'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 5,     'nome': 'Seis de Ouros',      'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 6,     'nome': 'Sete de Ouros',      'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 7,     'nome': 'Oito de Ouros',      'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 8,     'nome': 'Nove de Ouros',      'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 9,     'nome': 'Dez de Ouros',       'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 10,    'nome': 'Dama de Ouros',      'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 11,    'nome': 'Valete de Ouros',    'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 12,    'nome': 'Reis de Ouros',      'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 13,    'nome': 'Ás de Ouros',        'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdeouros.png')},
            { 'id': 14,    'nome': 'Dois de Espadas',    'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 15,    'nome': 'Três de Espadas',    'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 16,    'nome': 'Quatro de Espadas',  'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 17,    'nome': 'Cinco de Espadas',   'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 18,    'nome': 'Seis de Espadas',    'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 19,    'nome': 'Sete de Espadas',    'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 20,    'nome': 'Oito de Espadas',    'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 21,    'nome': 'Nove de Espadas',    'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 22,    'nome': 'Dez de Espadas',     'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 23,    'nome': 'Dama de Espadas',    'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 24,    'nome': 'Valete de Espadas',  'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 25,    'nome': 'Reis de Espadas',    'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 26,    'nome': 'Ás de Espadas',      'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdeespadas.png')},
            { 'id': 27,    'nome': 'Dois de Copas',      'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 28,    'nome': 'Três de Copas',      'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 29,    'nome': 'Quatro de Copas',    'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 30,    'nome': 'Cinco de Copas',     'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 31,    'nome': 'Seis de Copas',      'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 32,    'nome': 'Sete de Copas',      'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 33,    'nome': 'Oito de Copas',      'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 34,    'nome': 'Nove de Copas',      'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 35,    'nome': 'Dez de Copas',       'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 36,    'nome': 'Dama de Copas',      'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 37,    'nome': 'Valete de Copas',    'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 38,    'nome': 'Reis de Copas',      'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 39,    'nome': 'Ás de Copas',        'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Copas',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdecopas.png')},
            { 'id': 40,    'nome': 'Dois de Paus',       'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 41,    'nome': 'Três de Paus',       'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/tresdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 42,    'nome': 'Quatro de Paus',     'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/quatrodepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 43,    'nome': 'Cinco de Paus',      'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/cincodepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 44,    'nome': 'Seis de Paus',       'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/seisdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 45,    'nome': 'Sete de Paus',       'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/setedepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 46,    'nome': 'Oito de Paus',       'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/oitodepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 47,    'nome': 'Nove de Paus',       'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/novedepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 48,    'nome': 'Dez de Paus',        'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Paus,',     'image': require('@/assets/cartas/dezdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 49,    'nome': 'Dama de Paus',       'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/damadepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 50,    'nome': 'Valete de Paus',     'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/valetedepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 51,    'nome': 'Reis de Paus',       'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/reisdepaus.png')},
            { 'id': 52,    'nome': 'Ás de Paus',         'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Paus',      'image': require('@/assets/cartas/asdepaus.png')}           
        ],

        tamanhoDoBaralho: 0,

        cartasNaMao: [],

    }),

    mounted: function(){

    },

    methods: {

        sacarCartaDoBaralho(){

          let refId = 0;
          let indice = 0;

          refId = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.todasAsCartas.length);

          for (let i = 0; i <= this.todasAsCartas.length; i++){

            if ( i == refId ){
              indice = i;

            }

          }

          if (indice > -1 && this.todasAsCartas.length > 0){

            let cartaRetirada = this.todasAsCartas.splice(indice,1)
            this.cartasNaMao.push(cartaRetirada[0])
          }

        }

    }

}

</script>

<style>

.carta {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;

}

.botaoEstilizado {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: red;

}

.quebraDeLinha {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;

}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o problema está no componente `v-layout` provavelmente é uma lib que você está utilizando e talvez ela esteja usando flexbox.

Caso o `v-layout` use o `display: flex;` ele forma uma linha na horizontal infinita, isso pode ser resolvido com `flex-wrap: wrap;` que adiciona a quebra de linha, fiz um exemplo usando css, mas você tem de ver na documentação da sua lib qual a diretiva responsável pelo comportamento do `flex-wrap: wrap;`...

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        size: 'sm',
        baralhoTeste: [],

        numeroAleatorioGerado: [],

        todasAsCartas:[
            { 'id': 1,     'nome': 'Dois de Ouros',      'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 2,     'nome': 'Três de Ouros',      'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 3,     'nome': 'Quatro de Ouros',    'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 4,     'nome': 'Cinco de Ouros',     'valor': 5,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 5,     'nome': 'Seis de Ouros',      'valor': 6,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 6,     'nome': 'Sete de Ouros',      'valor': 7,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 7,     'nome': 'Oito de Ouros',      'valor': 8,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 8,     'nome': 'Nove de Ouros',      'valor': 9,     'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 9,     'nome': 'Dez de Ouros',       'valor': 10,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 10,    'nome': 'Dama de Ouros',      'valor': 11,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 11,    'nome': 'Valete de Ouros',    'valor': 12,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 12,    'nome': 'Reis de Ouros',      'valor': 13,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 13,    'nome': 'Ás de Ouros',        'valor': 14,    'naipe': 'Ouros',     'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 14,    'nome': 'Dois de Espadas',    'valor': 2,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 15,    'nome': 'Três de Espadas',    'valor': 3,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 16,    'nome': 'Quatro de Espadas',  'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 17,    'nome': 'Quatro de Espadas',  'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 18,    'nome': 'Quatro de Espadas',  'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'},
            { 'id': 19,    'nome': 'Quatro de Espadas',  'valor': 4,     'naipe': 'Espadas',   'image': 'https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-dp7DLax6Ri0%2FVS8tuu4xNdI%2FAAAAAAAAAIM%2FKTvI22eH_BQ%2Fs1600%2F26-10%252Bde%252Bouro.png&f=1'}
        ],

        tamanhoDoBaralho: 0,

        cartasNaMao: [],

    },

    mounted: function(){
        console.clear();
    },

    methods: {

        sacarCartaDoBaralho(){

          let refId = 0;
          let indice = 0;

          refId = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.todasAsCartas.length);

          for (let i = 0; i <= this.todasAsCartas.length; i++){

            if ( i == refId ){
              indice = i;

            }

          }

          if (indice > -1 && this.todasAsCartas.length > 0){

            let cartaRetirada = this.todasAsCartas.splice(indice,1)
            this.cartasNaMao.push(cartaRetirada[0])
          }

        }

    }
})
```

```css
#app{
  height: 500px;
}
.ctn-cartas {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.carta {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.botaoEstilizado {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: red;
}
.quebraDeLinha {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-container>
    <v-layout>

      <!-- card do game -->
      <v-card height dark full-width width="1000px">

        <!-- --Botão para sacar uma carta do monte-- -->

        <v-btn class="botaoEstilizado" @click="sacarCartaDoBaralho">
            Sacar +1
        </v-btn>

        <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

        <!-- --Inicio das Cartas da Mão do Player 1-- -->

        <h3 class="ma-4">Cartas na Mão</h3>

        <v-layout align-baseline row>
          <v-img class="ma-2 pa-3 carta" v-for="item in cartasNaMao" :key="item.id" :src="item.image"></v-img>
        </v-layout> 

        <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

        <!-- --Inicio do monte-- -->

        <h3 class="ma-4">Baralho</h3>
        <div class="ctn-cartas">
          <img class="ma-2 pa-3 carta" v-for="carta in todasAsCartas" :key="carta.id" :src="carta.image">
        </div>

        <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

      </v-card>     
      <!-- ►►►►►►►►►►►►► -->

    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```